# How to map Inner array reponse to columns in lwc

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components

Reponse from child component :

```json
    datafromparent {
        "pageSize": 5,
        "sObjectrecords": [{
            "Id": "0030m00000Xbbw7AAB",
            "FirstName": "Jennie",
            "LastName": "Shravya"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000XbHytAAF",
            "FirstName": "Puram",
            "LastName": "Anila"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000XbYULAA3",
            "FirstName": "Kumar",
            "LastName": "Pavan"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000YF2SBAA1",
            "FirstName": "Arya1234",
            "LastName": "Navaneeth"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000WyQ6ZAAV",
            "FirstName": "External Record",
            "LastName": "EXTREC2"
        },
           ...
        ],
        "totalCount": 32
    }
    parentDataTableComp.js: 4 datafromparent {
        "pageSize": 5,
        "sObjectrecords": [{
            "Id": "0030m00000Xbbw7AAB",
            "FirstName": "Jennie",
            "LastName": "Shravya"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000XbHytAAF",
            "FirstName": "Puram",
            "LastName": "Anila"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000XbYULAA3",
            "FirstName": "Kumar",
            "LastName": "Pavan"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000YF2SBAA1",
            "FirstName": "Arya1234",
            "LastName": "Navaneeth"
        }, {
            "Id": "0030m00000WyQ6ZAAV",
            "FirstName": "External Record",
            "LastName": "EXTREC2"
        },
           ...
        ],
        "totalCount": 32
    }
```

Can someone help me how to map my inner array reponse to columns  below

```js
const columns = [{
        label: 'First Name',
        fieldName: 'FirstName',
        class: 'cols',
        editable: true,
        sortable: true
    },
    {
        label: 'Last Name',
        fieldName: 'LastName',
        class: 'cols',
        editable: true,
        sortable: true
    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is a powerful tool for arrays mapping.
Assuming that your table data variable is called `tableData` :

```
this.tableData = datafromparent.sObjectrecords.map(sobject => ({
    FirstName: sobject.FirstName,
    LastName: sobject.LastName
}));
```